# unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION

Tags: php, magento-2.1

I am following a tutorial from a book named Magento cookbook. But even though I followed all the codes, I keep on getting this error.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'constSTATUS_PENDING'
>   (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\Packt\HelloWorld\Model\Subscription.php
>   on line 7

```
namespace Packt\HelloWorld\Model;
class Subscription extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{

    constSTATUS_PENDING = 'pending';
    constSTATUS_APPROVED = 'approved';
    constSTATUS_DECLINED = 'declined';

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        array $data = [])
    {

            parent::__construct($context,$registry, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    }

    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Packt\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel\Subscription');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a space after "const":

```
const STATUS_PENDING = 'pending';
const STATUS_APPROVED = 'approved';
const STATUS_DECLINED = 'declined';
```

Comment: the error is now gone but i got another

Comment: What error do you get now?

Comment: Fatal error: Class Packt\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel\Subscription contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource::_construct) in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\Packt\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel\Subscription.php on line 12

Comment: Can you post your current code cause it doesn't show an abstract function above. You should also make the function _construct() protected like in the class you are extending

Comment: I posted it on answers

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace Packt\HelloWorld\Model;

class Subscription extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel{


    const STATUS_PENDING = 'pending';
    const STATUS_APPROVED = 'approved';
    const STATUS_DECLINED = 'declined';

    public function __construct(

        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        array $data = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($context,$registry, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    }

    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Packt\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel\Subscription');
    }
}
```

this is my current code

Comment: Maybe you should move this to another question so this thread is clean

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in your Model but in your ResoureModel class "Packt\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel\Subscription". You should implement 2 abstract methods from the "Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource" class:

```
abstract protected function _construct();
abstract protected function getConnection();
```

Comment: I already figured out my error Thank you so much!